# Unable to send signup test data to mlab (using MongoLab - Mongoose- Express - EJS - NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mongoose, ejs, mlab

I'm a new account holder in stackoverflow and it's my first time to post a question. being a newbie in programming, I just follow tutorials I found in the net just to learn. in my little project at home, I am **unable to send data to mlab** despite the following circumstances:

- initially, I was SUCCESSFUL in submitting (signup) data to my mlab account USING chrome-plugin POSTMAN

BUT when I transferred the code to the webpage and introduced sessions and cookies, I'm getting the following results ...

1) ubuntu terminal results shows ...

> GET /signup?name=john&email=john%40mail.com.com&password=123 200 ...

2) the **browser did not redirect to the homepage**. it remained in the signup page and **old data in the input fields keep showing**

THE INTENDED BEHAVIOR IS THAT
2.1) if I am signing up a NON-UNIQUE EMAIL, I should receive an alert message "this email address already exist" on top of the signup page

2.2) if I am signing up a UNIQUE EMAIL, I should be redirected to the homepage, AND a new user account is created in mlab.com

3) there is no added data in my mlab.com sandbox account

4) under the chrome inspect -- console, it shows NO ERROR whatsoever

I've tried to reviewing the video tutorials but to no avail, I still end up receiving the same results.

my development environment:

> ```
> - ubuntu 16.04
> - nodejs v6.9.1
> - npm v3.10.8
> ```

PACKAGE.JSON DEPENDENCIES:

> ```
> "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
> "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
> "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
> "ejs": "^2.5.2",
> "ejs-mate": "^2.3.0",
> "express": "^4.14.0",
> "express-flash": "0.0.2",
> "express-session": "^1.14.1",
> "mongoose": "^4.6.5",
> "morgan": "^1.7.0",
> ```

[the folder structure and server.js middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmMGX.png)

[user.js routes content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG5P9.png)

```
var router = require('express').Router(); var User =
require('../models/user');

// ----- SIGNUP PAGE (GET) // replace 'app' with 'router'
router.get('/signup', function(req, res, nxt) {
    res.render('accounts/signup', {
      errors: req.flash('errors')
    }); });

// ---------- END


// ----- SIGNUP PAGE (POST) // replace 'app' with 'router'
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, nxt) {
    var user = new User();

    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email}, function(err, existingUser) {
        if (existingUser) {

            // console.log(req.body.email + " already exist."); --> used in postman
            req.flash('errors', 'this email address already exist.');
            return res.redirect('/signup');
        } else {
            user.save(function(err, user) {
                if (err) return nxt(err);

                // res.json("New user created."); --> used in postman
                return res.redirect('/');
            });
        }
    }); });

module.exports = router;
```

/accounts/signup.ejs

```
<% layout('boilerplate') -%>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <% if (errors.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" arial-label="Close">
            <span arial-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <%= errors %>
        </div>
      <% } %>

        <form method-"post" autocomplete="off">

            <div class="form-group">
                <h1 class="form-signup-heading">sign up here</h1>
                <label="name">name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label="name">email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label="name">password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">sign up</button>
        </form>
    </div> </div>
```

any help from the community would be greatly appreciated.

best regards to everyone.

Comment: add `method action` attributes to form

Comment: hi Medet, i tried it. YES, its NOW being REDICTED to the HOME page (<form action="/"), thank you for the suggestion, BUT still the test data IS NOT BEING SENT to mlab.com. Also I observed, three (3) things when i refresh the signup page, ... 1) the old "GET /signup?name=john&email=john%40mail.com.com&password=123 200 ..." is showing in the terminal; ... 2) the signup form still retains YET another old signup data ("bong") i used before i used "john"; ... 3) STILL the mlab database IS NOT BEING POPULATED by a new user data. :(

Comment: Try this, in your server.js file there must be a connection to database, make sure database connected (inside connect callback log something). You probably not connected to mLab database, as your local server probably uses `mongodb://localhost:27017`

Comment: hi Medet, here's the code on top of the server.js ... <!-- 
// connect to the database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:xxxxx@ds013569.mlab.com:13569/amaclone', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("amaclone is now connected to mLab.com ...");
    }
}); -->

Comment: still on top ...  var express = require('express');  
var morgan = require('morgan');  
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
var ejs = require('ejs');  
var engine = require('ejs-mate');  
var expressSession = require('express-session');  
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');  
var flash = require('express-flash');  

// use User object from user.js  
var User = require('./models/user');  

var app = express();

Comment: please also note that i changed the mlab.com credentials for the purpose of this interaction :)